# VSTS on Visual Studio (Mac)

Tags: macos, visual-studio, azure-devops

I am trying to connect to my VSTS company, but when I go to the website, I say open up in Visual Studio, nothing happens. Also, there is no connect tool.

I googled variety of things, but I am assuming that Visual Studio for Mac does not support VSTS(?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click the "Open in Visual Studio" link from the VSTS Web Portal, it will call "Microsoft Visual Studio Web Protocol Handler Selector" which is only supported on Windows OS. So it won't work on Mac OS X.

[image]

And another thing is that Visual Studio for Mac only supports Git and Subversion for version control. TFVC is not supported for now. If you are using Git in VSTS, you can connect to it from Visual Studio for Mac\Version Control\Checkout and then select "Git" as repository type. For TFVC, please vote the feature request here: [TFS Version Control](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/563332-visual-studio-for-mac/suggestions/17136163-tfs-support).

Answer (score 1):

Team Foundation Version Control (TFS TFVC) is now supported for Visual Studio on Mac since version 7.5+

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2018/05/07/visual-studio-for-mac-version-7-5-and-beyond/

As of 06/11/2018 Visual Studio has created another update which will support past the issues with the login,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/tf-version-control